# Batch file for executing set of commands to start an application

Tags: batch-file, cmd

We have an application. To start that application 8 to 10 commands has to be executed from within a command prompt window. I want to create a batch file to run those ten commands. I tried the batch code below, but couldn't get it working. We use Ruby.

Here are my commands:

```
set PATH=D:\Installables\jruby-bin-1.7.20\jruby-1.7.20\bin;%PATH%
set PATH=D:\Installables\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin;%PATH%
set http_proxy=http://:@xxx.xxx.xx.x:xxxx
cd /D "D:\Installables\ansi160\x64"
ansicon.exe
cd /D "D:\folder"
gem install bundler         & rem takes few seconds to complete
bundle install              & rem takes few seconds to complete
bundle exec rake db:migrate & rem takes few seconds to complete
bundle exec rails s         & rem takes few seconds to complete
```

The batch file execution stops after running `ansicon.exe`.

Comment: Errrrm.... Copy those commands, paste them into a batch-file (file-ending .bat). Open a command-line and run your batch-file in there (you can drag and drop the file and press enter). Do you get any error messages? If yes try to resolve them by yourself using google and the SO search. If not, try to break down your problem to the minimum and come back with a new question. I encourage you to take the [tour] as well :)

Comment: I tried, the commands are executing fine till "D:" after that the commands don t execute. I had all these commands in one batch file and used another batch file to call this.

Comment: So you are saying there are no error messages? Since you are not suppressing an verbose output you should see all the commands executing and any error messages.

Comment: If `ansicon` is a .bat or .cmd script, you must use `CALL` or it will never return.

Comment: @Mofi ansion is a exe file. after that command gets executed, the command to move to the directory fails "cd D:\folder".  Console stops with the below line
    ' D:\Installables\ansi160\x64>' 
Also I didn t get any error, just the console stops

Comment: There are no spaces in the folder, I tried without that ansicon step the batch file works, with that ansicon step the execution stops(is it because ansicon is an exe file??). Is there any way to keep the command prompt window alive after the batch file finishes?? I tried using \C but its giving error "\C is not an internal external command"

Comment: `\C` is definitely wrong. On Windows parameters start with a slash `/` and backslash ``\`` is used as a directory separator. To see what is going on, open a command prompt window (starts `cmd.exe` with `/K` to keep window open) and run first `cmd /?` to get displayed the help for the Windows command interpreter. Next run from within the command prompt window your batch file by entering its name with full path enclosed in double quotes. You can see now what is executed by Windows command interpreter.

Comment: Perhaps `ansicon.exe` is not a real compiled executable, but a batch file packed into an executable. Try out what happens on using in your batch file `call ansicon.exe`. The command `call` is usually only needed for calling a batch file from within a batch file, but can be also used for executables which sometimes makes a difference. If that also does not work, use `start "" /wait ansicon.exe` to run this executable in a separate command process and halt batch execution until this separate command process terminated itself after `ansicon.exe` terminated.

Comment: Tried \K and executed the batch file from within the command prompt itself, still the execution stops in ansicon. This is the ansicon [link] (https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/downloads) (first link).

Answer (score 0):

yeah you are switching over to `ansicon.exe` instead of starting it, thus stopping the script. You either need to start it (`start "" "ansicon.exe"`) or call it (`call ansicon.exe`) if you need what it does in your file.